# сохранить/закешировать bool переменную на время сессии с возможностью перезагрузки страницы

Tags: javascript, localstorage

Каким образом можно сохранить/закешировать `bool` переменную на время сессии с возможностью перезагрузки страницы, но когда закрыв вкладку обнулять, что-то на подобии такого

```
localStorage.setItem('rebuild', 'true');
var bool = localStorage.getItem('rebuild');

window.onscroll = function(){
  var scrollT = window.pageYOffset;
  if(scroll > 300 && bool === true){
    init("canvas");
    bool = false;
  }
}
```

и потом заменить выше на время сессии?

Comment: [sessionStorage - это localStorage, но только на время сессии](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)

Comment: _bool === true_ - это условие **всегда** будет _false_ потому что в localStorage хранятся только строки

Comment: @Grundy но `sessionStorage` после перезагрузки пропадает, а мне нужно так, чтобы она обнулялась  после закрытия страницы, думал через куки, но как-то не правильно наверное

Comment: нет, не пропадает после перезагрузки

Comment: @Grundy тогда та ссылочка, что выше, я могу перезаписать переменную на время сессии и после перезагрузки оно будет тащить уже `false`?

Comment: смотря на что перезапишешь

Comment: @Grundy на false

Comment: В заголовке должна быть описана суть вопроса, а не просьбы о помощи )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

решил таким образом

```
function getParam (){

        if(sessionStorage.getItem('rebuild') == '0'){
            tempVar = sessionStorage.getItem('rebuild');
            init('canvas');
        } else {
            sessionStorage.setItem('rebuild', '1');
            tempVar = sessionStorage.getItem('rebuild');
        }


    }
    getParam();

    window.onscroll = function(){
      var scrollT = window.pageYOffset;
      if(scroll > 300 && tempVar == '1'){
        init('canvas');
        tempVar = '0';
      }
    }

    if(tempVar === '0'){
        sessionStorage.setItem('rebuild', '0');
    }
```

Спасибо @Grundy, за помощь:)

Если где-то не правильно, буду благодарен за советы!